# Removing Baground Link From Slideshow

Tags: views

Hello i Am Using Drupal 7 and created  a slideshow using views and views slideshow so in slideshow when a user is clicking the image url is opening you can also check my slideshow at Windowhelpdesk.com When Anyone Clicks on image a url is opening i want to remove that url plz anyone help me to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the image field to views, make sure to set it to 'Link image to: Nothing'

[image]